# htaccess will not work

Tags: .htaccess

On my new vps.net server .htaccess does not work. mod_rewrite is what the .htaccess is trying to do.

These are the steps I have done so far:

Added:

```
<Directory "/var/www/*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

To `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Restart apache. `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

No luck.

Verified the .htaccess is actually there, it is.

Verified my apache2.conf has the line `AccessFileName .htaccess`, it does.

Edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Changed:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>
```

to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restart apache. `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

No luck.

Do not know what to try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `rewrite.load` appear in `/etc/apache/mods-enabled/`?

If not, does it appear in `/etc/apache/mods-available/`?

If it's in the latter and not the former, `a2enmod rewrite` and another restart of Apache should set you on your way -- this just creates a symlink in `-enabled` to the file in `-available` which tells Apache to load that module.

If that doesn't work, do you get anything in `/var/log/apache/error.log` (or wherever your Apache instance logs its errors?)

Comment: Oh, excellent. Ignore my edit about error logs then :-)